# Emission of photoelectrons

Tags: photoelectric-effect

The ejection of photoelectrons is independent of the intensity of radiation. But the quantity of electrons ejected depends on the intensity. So is there a limit to how much the intensity has to be, below which zero photoelectrons are ejected even if the frequency is sufficient for an emission?

Answer (score 0):

No, if the intensity is low the amount of photons hitting the surface becomes lower. But if they have the necessary amount of energy, they cause the effect. Whether or not the effect is caused is independent of the intensity.

Answer (score 0):

The occurrence of the photo effect as many other scattering processes can be characterized by a cross section. As the question is about indiscriminate occurrence of the photo effect I will here give the total cross section of the process using the following abreviations: $\alpha \approx 1/137$ is the fine structure constant, $a_0=5.29\cdot 10^{-9}$cm  is the Bohr's radius, and
$I_0$ the ionisation energy of hydrogen (13.5eV).

$\nu$ is the frequency of the incoming photons, and $h$ corresponds to Planck's constant $h=\hbar \cdot (2\pi)$.

then according to Landau/Lifshitz Vol. 4 :

$$\sigma_{photo} = \frac{2^8 \pi}{3}\alpha a_0^2 Z^5\left(\frac{I_0}{h \nu}\right)^{7/2}$$

The formula is valid for photon frequencies which are significantly larger than the ionisation energy. Of course the energy of the photons is supposed to be significantly smaller than the rest energy of an electron, i.e. $511$keV.

Remarkable is here the strong dependence of the photo effect on the atomic number $Z$.

So in case of an incoming photon intensity $I_i$ the intensity of ejected electrons is $I_e$

$$I_e = I_i n \sigma_{photo} d$$

As in most cases $\sigma_{photo}$ is rather small the number of occurred photo effects, i.e. ejected electrons will be rather small compared to the number of incoming photons.

The parameters $n$ are the number density of atoms of the exposed material (for instance silicon in case of photovoltaic cells) and $d$ is the thickness of the exposed material.

So in case that only one photon arrives, it can indeed eject an electron from the exposed material, however, the probability that to happen remains small in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some [Chandra X-ray Observatory](https://chandra.harvard.edu/) observations see objects whose intensity corresponds to less than one photon per hour in the photoelectric detectors. There is no empirical or theoretical lower limit to the photoelectric rate. There are, however, "background" electrons liberated by other processes (charged particles and Compton scattered gamma rays). The (very faint) "fog" of these ultimately limits Chandra's sensitivity.